# Multiple angular select tags

Tags: javascript, database-performance

I'm trying to generate multiple select tags with the same option tags and values. It's a user table that will show the username, then the group that is selected for them, but I am having trouble selecting the correct one for each user instead of changing them all.

```js
var app = angular.module('todo',[]);

app.controller('option_list',function($scope){

  $scope.users = [
    {"id":0, "group_id":0, "name":"Caleb"},
    {"id":1, "group_id":2, "name":"Christie"},
    {"id":2, "group_id":0, "name":"Dawson"},
    {"id":3, "group_id":0, "name":"Kalen"}
  ]
  $scope.groups = [
    {"id":0, "name":"First Group"},
    {"id":1, "name":"Second Group"},
    {"id":2, "name":"Third Group"},
    {"id":3, "name":"Fourth Group"}
  ]
  for(var i = 0; i < $scope.users.length; i++){
    $scope.selected = {
      group: $scope.groups[$scope.users[i].group_id]
    }
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


      <div class="container" ng-app="todo">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12" id="task_list" ng-controller="option_list">
            <table class="table">
              <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
                  <td>{{user.name}}</td>
                  <td>
                    <select class="form-control" ng-model="selected.group" ng-options="group as group.name for group in groups"></select>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>


          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: You just have the same _ng-model_ for every user. Make them different.

Comment: Do you think you could show me programmatically? I set the ng-model in the select tag to [code]groups[user.group_id][/code] and it works but once one is switched, it changes all of them that have the same value.

Comment: Try this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/22821/) PS Disclaimer: I am not good with angular... so, you better check it twice.

Comment: As far as I know, these wouldn't be strings but objects.

Comment: I removed the web worker tab because I don't see anything about web workers here. If you can explain why this is related to web workers, re add the tag please.